# How To Implement Form authentication Security in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

i have employee and department  in database and 3 types of users should be logged in

first>admin can add update and delete records for departments and employees and assign depart manager

second> depart managers can view employee's data of their departments

third> employees just view their own data

how to use forms authentication to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the built-in [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw292whz.aspx) functionality to authenticate users, in conjunction with the built-in [Role Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ab2fxh0(v=vs.100).aspx) functionality to authorize them.

In you're case you'd probably define roles such as "manager", "admin", "employee".

Answer (score 0):

I have found quite good and simple example of form authentication once upon a time on codeproject:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/297597/ASP-NET-Membership